# Depending on another element from a list

Tags: gitlab, terraform, terraform-provider-gitlab

I am trying to create the hierarchy of Gitlab groups from scratch. Since it may grow out itself, I wouldn't want to create separate resources for every group, so I tried to create a custom module and create the groups from a list by going through with a for_each:

```
module "gitlab_groups" {
  for_each = local.groups
  source = "./modules/group"
  name = each.value.name path = each.value.path parent_group = try(each.value.parent_group, null) 
}
```

This is working great until all the groups has no parent. The problem is that if the parent group is provided, it will read the parent group's data BEFORE the parent group itself is created.

Related code snippet from the module:

```
data "gitlab_group" "parent" {
  count = var.parent_group == null ? 0 : 1
  full_path = var.parent_group 
}

resource "gitlab_group" "group" {
  name = var.name
  path = var.path
  parent_id = var.parent_group == null ? null : data.gitlab_group.parent[0].group_id 
}
```

Log from `terraform apply` command:

```
module.gitlab_groups[1].data.gitlab_group.parent[0]: Reading...
module.gitlab_groups[0].gitlab_group.group: Creating...
module.gitlab_groups[0].gitlab_group.group: Creation complete after 1s [id=56]
```

Is there any way to force dependency on another element in the list beside creating separate resources for every group and set the `depends_on` manually?

I am using the following versions if it is necessary:

```
> terraform --version
Terraform v1.0.0
on windows_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/gitlabhq/gitlab v3.6.0
```

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
The initial idea was to create a dynamic group hierarchy where we don't have to manually re-wire subgroups to a new in-between parent.
[image: sample image]

If I would like to introduce a new group between the Subgroup2 and its subgroups, I would have to manually set the dependencies between each other and while it is not really a problem with a few groups, it can be a real issue with a big enough number of groups.

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies in Terraform are between the declaration blocks (the `resource` and `data` blocks) and not between the instances that result from evaluating them, because the `count` and `for_each` arguments are themselves subject to dependencies. For that reason I don't think the problem you've described here is very amenable to the module design you've attempted, and I think you'd be better served by writing `resource "github_group"` blocks directly and using normal Terraform references to connect them together.

The multiple instances of a since resource are all conceptually handled concurrently in Terraform, although in practice Terraform limits its concurrency and so the result will typically be the operations completing in some undefined order.

If you need a particular order of operations then you'll need to declare two separate resources with dependencies between them. However, you should not need to use `depends_on` because each child object would refer to its parent's id anyway.

The other thing I see about your configuration is that it seems like you are attempting to both manage a group and retrieve that group using a data source in the same configuration. That's a pretty tricky pattern to get right because you'd need to explain to Terraform that it should not try to read an object before it's been created or updated. Instead, the best practice is to use the upstream resource object itself to populate the downstream resource, so that the downstream objects will refer directly to the upstream objects and thus the dependency graph will automatically be correct.

Comment: I was trying to create a dynamic solution for managing group hierarchy. I know I could depend on  separate blocks, but it would be really challenging if the group hierarchy is big enough. Imagine I have a pretty big project with more then 30+ group in 4+ depth. If I would like to introduce a new in-between group then I would have to re-wire all the dependencies that was referencing the old parent to point to the new one. The data block is trying to fetch data for the **parent group** of the subgroup that the resource would create.